# Is sequence $(b_n) = n \cos (\frac{n! \pi}{2^{10}})$ is bounded or unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am working on the following entrance exam problem.

> Let Sequence $(a_n) =  (1+1/n)^n$, $n \in \mathbb {N}$. Then I have to check that sequence $(a_n)$ is convergent or divergent?
> and
>
> Sequence $(b_n) = n \cos (\frac{n! \pi}{2^{10}})$ is bounded or
> unbounded?

**My attempt** Sequence ($a_n$) is convergent because its limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is $e$, proving convergence to $e$.

However, I'm uncertain whether sequence $b_n$ is bounded or unbounded. Sequence $b_n$  is the product of two sequences: $n$ and $\cos (\frac{n! \pi}{2^{10}})$. This leads me to consider it might be unbounded, as $n$ is unbounded, and the maximum value of sequence involving Cosine is 1.

On the other hand, I also contemplate that if, for some $n$,' the $\cos$ value becomes zero, can I then assert that $b_n$ is bounded for those particular $n$?" or perhaps there isn't such a possibility.

Kindly help me with this.

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: if $n \ge 14$, then $n! = 2^{10} \cdot 2k$ for some integer $k \in \mathbb N_+$. In particular, $\cos(\frac{n! \pi}{2^{10}}) = \cos(2\pi k) = 1$.

Comment: Hint: $\cos (k\pi) = \pm 1$.

Comment: For large $n$, $\frac{n!}{2^{10}}$ is even and hence $n\cos(\frac{n!\pi}{2^{10}})=n$.

Comment: @DominikKutek Thanks for the response. Could you please write this as an answer with little more detail?

Comment: @xpaul Thank you so much for the response.  I would greatly appreciate more details regarding this fact. Could you please assist me further?

Comment: @Srijan, no problem.

Comment: @xpaul Thank you sir

Comment: $(a_n)$ is well known to tend to $e$ , so you have done this right.

Comment: @peter Dear sir thanks for your comment. Confused with the sequence $(b_n)$.

Comment: @Peter Dear sir Based on your comments and those above, I've understood that sequence $b_n$ is unbounded. However, I would like to see a proof for these facts, particularly the one that explains why 'Cosine' becomes an integer for large n  or $cos(2 \pi k)$

Comment: The cosine is periodic with length $2\pi$ and $\cos(0)=1$. My comment was a bit sloppy because it did not distinguish between unbounded in one direction and unbounded in both directions (upper and lower bound). If you show the argument is eventually an integer you have shown that the expression cannot be bounded in both directions. If you show it is eventually an even integer , you can conclude that there is no upper bound for the expression.